# Script tag support - error : macrodef doesn't support the nested "script" element

Tags: java, ant

I am working on some code block on Apache ANT

```
<target name="workload">
        <script language="javascript"><![CDATA[ 
            println("<div id='collapseOne' class='accordion-body collapse in'><div class='accordion-inner'><pre>"); ]]>
        </script>

        <apply dir="${dir.publish.ini}" executable="java" parallel="false" failonerror="false">
            <fileset dir="${dir.ini}">
                <include name="**/*.ini"/> 
            </fileset>
            <arg value="-jar" />
            <arg path="${tool}" />
            <srcfile/>
        </apply>

        <script language="javascript"><![CDATA[ println("</pre></div></div>"); ]]></script>         
    </target>
```

When i use `<antcall target="workload"/>` 
It's working fine.

I have to optimize this code block. So i tried using following code:

```
<macrodef name="workload">
            <script language="javascript"><![CDATA[ 
                println("<div id='collapseOne' class='accordion-body collapse in'><div class='accordion-inner'><pre>"); ]]>
            </script>

            <apply dir="${dir.publish.html}" executable="java" parallel="false" failonerror="false">
                <fileset dir="${dir.ini}">
                    <include name="**/*.ini"/> 
                </fileset>
                <arg value="-jar" />
                <arg path="${tool}" />
                <srcfile/>
            </apply>

            <script language="javascript"><![CDATA[ println("</pre></div></div>"); ]]></script>         
        </macrodef>
```

And when i called `<antcall target="workload"/>` It showed me the following error:

```
macrodef doesn't support the nested "script" element.
```

Which it macrodef does not support script! How can overcome this? or Is there any better way to optimize my build.xml code block?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are converting task inside target to macrodef for reuse. In that case,  capture the logic inside `sequential` block of macrodef.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html

Comment: It's, Working now. But is write way to use macrodef instead of target. Because when i was using target it tool 10 seconds to complete my task and with macrodef it tool 15 seconds !

Comment: Looks okay. Is it slow when invoking multiple times as part of same build step?

Comment: You guess it correctly; Yes! I am invoking it multiple times as part of same build step..